# Не работает transition css у absolute-img

Tags: css

```
.absolute
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -170px;
    transition: all 3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    padding: 20px; 
}

.absolute-img
{
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; 
  width: 70%;
  top: unset;
  height: auto;
}

.icon_box_one:hover .absolute
{
  bottom: 50px;
}

.icon_box_one:hover .absolute-img
{
  top: -50px;
  transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Анимирование в `css` - последовательная подстановка **промежуточных** значений свойства. Для пары значений `top` : `unset` и `-50px` невозможно подобрать промежуточные значения. Точно так-же как, например,  для `auto` и `-50px`. 
Этот принцип работает как в `transition` так и в `animation`.

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -170px;
  transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  padding: 20px;
}

.absolute-img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  width: 70%;
  top: 0; /*тут надо использовать цифровое значение*/
  height: auto;
}

.icon_box_one:hover .absolute {
  bottom: 50px;
}

.icon_box_one:hover .absolute-img {
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon_box_one">
  <img class="absolute-img" src="https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1rbL3PpXXXXXaapXXq6xXFXXXF/Soccer-ball-custom-logo-football-mini-balls.jpg"  width="50" />
</div>
```